# How to find a match using "while"

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to find a random number between 1-100000 that divided with 7 & 13 & 15,
the loop should run until it find the right number,
I'm trying to do:

```
from random import randint
while True:
    for x in range (1,100000):
        if x % 7 == 0 and x % 13 ==0 and x % 15 == 0:
        print x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a list comprehension:

```
l=[x for x in range(1,100000) if x % 7 == 0 and x % 13 == 0 and x % 15 == 0]
```

Then, to select a random value from that list, change the top line to `import random`, and you can do:

```
random.choice(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know, 7,13 and 15 are co-primes, then, we should start from 7*13*15 = 1365. Then you can apply @numbermaniac solution.

```
import random 
random.choice([i for i in xrange(1365,1000000) if i%1365 == 0])
```

another solution might be,

```
# select random number between your upper_limit/1365
# then multiplying it 1365
random.randint(1, 732)*1365
```

Comment: Nice optimisation! Small nitpick: Original question used a maximum of 100,000, while yours uses 1,000,000.

Comment: i've lost inside zeros -))

Comment: No worries, haha. With your new edit, I think 733 should be 732, since `randint` is inclusive, and if it returns 733, that times 1365 would be 1,000,545, which is above the maximum of a million :)

Comment: sure -)) i do  not even remember it is inclusive or not. let me fix it. btw second one is a lot faster for big ranges - rather than iteration.